QGIS - GPKG appears in wrong hemisphere
I am attempting to make use of a GPKG produced by a US federal agency (that does a lot of mapping) that is misbehaving.  I have another similar GPKG from the same agency that works as expected.
The following steps should describe what I am encountering.
Started a new QGIS (3.34) project, used QuickMapServices to load OSM Standard as background, which set project CRS to EPSG:3857.  Adding the background first was suggested as part of a solution to another question, which is why I did it.
Dropped GPKG_1 (MultiPolygon - EPSG:4269) onto map, came out in the desired area which is the United States.
Dropped GPKG_2 (MultiSurface - EPSG:4269) onto map, appeared on and around Antarctica, south of Africa.  The map (still in EPSG:3857) looks like the following:
Changed project CRS to EPSG:4269, map now looks like:
Both GPKGs are well over 1 GB in size, so I doubt if anyone wants to download them to try.
Any suggestions?

Is it possible the X & Y coordinates have been reversed? Try running Swap X and Y coordinates from the processing toolbox on GPKG_2.

That did the trick, Ben W!  Worked perfectly!

I suggest you to contact the US federal agency in order to make them aware that they are sharing inaccurate data.

Andrea Guidiceandrea - That agency updates the GPKG every couple of days.  I expect the current problem was the result of a careless mistake.  If the next version has the same problem I will certainly notify them.  Thanks!
